# Laravel: Upload form data with images in a foreach loop using Intervention

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and would like to have a form with a few rows of text fields with their corresponding image uploads.

Form:

```
<div id="row">
    <input name="description[]" type="text">
    <input name="image[]" type="file">
</div>
<div id="row">
    <input name="description[]" type="text">
    <input name="image[]" type="file">
</div>
```

Controller:

```
foreach($request->description as $key => $val){

if($val != null){
    $data = new Finding;
    $data->description = $val; //save description for each loop

    $file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));

    if (Input::file('image')->isValid()) {

        $destinationPath = 'uploads';
        $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = rand(1000,1000).'.'.$extension;
        Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        $path = Input::file('image')->getRealPath();

        $data->image_location = $fileName[$key]; //save filename location to db
        $data->save();

        flash('success', 'Uploaded Successful');
        return Redirect::to('/upload');
     } else {
        flash('error', 'Uploaded File Is Not Valid');
        return Redirect::to('/upload');
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I use intervention with the `$key` value to save a new row in the table with the associated text description with the image upload and still use all the intervention classes? Is my code close?

I can easily do all this with just one form input with one image upload but my goal is to have a page with multiple rows with inputs. Thanks!

Comment: What's intervention?

Comment: @haakym http://image.intervention.io/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm unsure of how you're managing the multiple fields, whether it's set in stone or can dynamically change. I have previously done dynamic approaches with javascript and kept track of how many dynamic fields I required with a hidden text field as a count.

Using this approach your html might look something like this:

```
<input name="imageAndDescriptionCount" type="hidden" value="2">
<div id="row">
    <input name="description[]" type="text">
    <input name="image[]" type="file">
</div>
<div id="row">
    <input name="description[]" type="text">
    <input name="image[]" type="file">
</div>
```

So here we have two image and description fields each and the counter is set at 2.

If we were to submit the form and checkout the request via `dd()` it would look something like this:

```
"imageAndDescriptionCount" => "2"
"description" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "description"
    1 => "description"
]
    "image" => array:2 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#154 ▶}
    1 => UploadedFile {#155 ▶}
]
```

This then sets you up nicely for a for loop in your controller:

```
$count = $request->get('imageAndDescriptionCount');
$description = $request->get('description'); // assign array of descriptions
$image = $request->file('image'); // assign array of images

// set upload path using https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-storage-path 
// make sure 'storage/uploads' exists first
$destinationPath = storage_path . '/uploads'; 

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    $data = new Finding;
    $data->description = [$i];

    $file = $image[$i];

    if ($file->isValid()) {
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // file extension
        $fileName = uniqid(). '.' .$extension; // file name with extension
        $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // move file to our uploads path

        $data->image_location = $fileName;
        // or you could say $destinationPath . '/' . $fileName
        $data->save();
    } else {
        // handle error here
    }

}

flash('success', 'Uploads Successful');
return Redirect::to('/upload');
```

Please note there is no use of the intervention library in your code to my knowledge and I've just wrote the code to perform the upload. I hope this helps you!

**Edit**

If you really want to use a foreach loop and you know you'll have a description  for each image you can do it like this (but I personally think having a counter is a better approach)

```
$descriptions = $request->get('description'); // assign array of descriptions
$images = $request->file('image'); // assign array of images

// loop through the descriptions array
foreach($descriptions as $key => $val) {

    // You can access the description like this
    $val
    // or this
    $descriptions[$key]

    // so naturally you can access the image like this:
    $images[$key]

}
```

You could also instead check the count of the descriptions/images and use that as a counter to loop through:

```
$descriptions = $request->get('description');
$images = $request->file('image'); // assign array of images

$descCount = count($descriptions);
$imgCount = count($images);
```

If however you may have a different layout, i.e. you don't have 1 description for 1 image then please clarify as you'd need to take a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. While your response is logical the only thing is that on the html form I'm using a "Add Another Image" button function that clones the `table tr` so from the controller side the amount of images with descriptions would be unknown so I'm trying to go with the foreach loop instead of a hard count like you have suggested

Comment: I'm not saying to hard code it. Use the counter value dynamically, update its value when you add (click "Add Another Image" button function) or remove a row with javascript. I assume every time you add a row you add one extra description and one extra image, they come as a pair right? So it should work fine with my approach you just have to add the code to update the counter value.

Comment: That is true. Let me give it a shot

Comment: All the best. Do update your question if you get stuck on something.